# CXF-java2wsdl-plugin not importing external schema defined in @XmlSchema annotation

Tags: jaxb, xsd, jax-ws, cxf

I'm using the cxf-java2ws-plugin to generate a WSDL file from JAX-WS annotated classes. For my data objects; I'm specifying the fact that an external schema file already exists (by adding an @XmlSchema annotation with a location attribute to the package-info.java file). When the WSDL file gets generated; the namespace for the imported schema is declared; but the schema file itself is never imported. This results in a malformed schema.

My plugin configuration is as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process-classes</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <configuration>
                <className>com.mycorp.hello.HelloWebService</className>
                <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <outputFile>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/HelloWebService.wsdl</outputFile>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>java2ws</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is an example of the package-info.java file:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(location="http://localhost:16899/schema/model.xsd", namespace="urn:ws.mycorp.com:hello:model")
package com.mycorp.hello.model;
```

Here is the pre-existing schema file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:ws.mycorp.com:hello:model" xmlns:tns="urn:ws.mycorp.com:hello:model" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <complexType name="MessageObject">
    <sequence>
        <element name="message" nillable="true" type="string"></element>
    </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Here is the generated schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="urn:ws.mycorp.com:hello:model" xmlns:tns="http://hello.mycorp.com/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://hello.mycorp.com/" version="1.0">
<xs:import namespace="urn:ws.mycorp.com:hello:model"/>
<xs:element name="getHelloMessage" type="tns:getHelloMessage"/>
<xs:element name="getHelloMessageResponse" type="tns:getHelloMessageResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="getHelloMessage">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getHelloMessageResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="ns1:messageObject"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Note how the "urn:ws.mycorp.com:hello:model" namespace is declared and imported but is lacking the actual schema location (http://localhost:16899/schema/model.xsd). As a result, the generated schema has an error since ns1:messageObject cannot be found.

Obviously, I could manually modify the generated schema; but this becomes a nuisance since I'd have to do it every time the code is modified... and in a real world scenario (I put together this simple test case to illustrate the problem), there might be more than 1 pre-existing schema file.

EDIT:After doing a bit more research on this, I believe the problem is that JAXB requires a catalog file:

http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Fixing_broken_references_in_schema.html

The catalog file would allow JAXB to resolve the existing namespace (urn:ws.mycorp.com:hello:model) to an actual location. Unfortunately, the java2ws cxf tool seems to lack options to customize the JAXB databinding process:

http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/jira-Resolved-CXF-1693-Allow-custom-Jaxb-databinding-in-java2ws-just-like-in-wsdl2java-td4787407.html

And the documentation from jaxb that indicates how to pass the catalog file assumes jaxb is getting invoked directly(either via ant/maven or the command line CLI tool); which isn't the case with java2ws...